# Aligning multiple Tikz nodes by their shared bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a reusable element for a project using tikz, but I am having trouble aligning the elements neatly. I will later feed content for these elements from CSV-files, but one step at a time.

My goal is to make a figure like so:
[image: desired figure]

It is an outer box containing a 25x25mm imagebox at its vertical center, with 3 nodes next to it, containing a header-text, a description-text and a table of variable size. The outer box and imagebox are under control, but positioning the other three nodes correctly is giving me some trouble.

I want the vertical center of the collective bounding box of the ProdHeader-node, ProdDesc-node and ProdTable to be aligned with the vertical center of the imagebox.

I have tried a few different ways

- Placing them in a matrix. While that did work for positioning, the matrix did not play nice with the nested table.
- Nesting them as \tikz\node within a main node also positioned them correctly, but made them inherit attributes they should not.
- Placing them in a table-enviroment (tabular, tabularx, NiceTabular, tblr), and once again, the issue was mainly not playing nicely with the nested table.
- Current attempt is trying with fit, but as fit requires the nodes to be placed first, this doesn't really help.

The most basic solution is to anchor ProdDesc.west (the middle element) next to imagebox.east, but this makes the outer box extend further downwards than upwards, which looks bad, as illustrated here:

[image: alignment of elements look bad, using the method of the above paragraph]

**My code:**

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds,calc}
        
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
    
%coordinate for use in fitting the outerbox correctly; box extended beyond page is intentional
    \node [anchor=west] (start) at (current page.west){};

%imagebox placement, works as intended
    \node[draw, text width=25mm, minimum height=25mm, anchor=west, baseline=center](imagebox) at ($(start)+(12mm,0)$) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=25mm, width=25mm,clip]{example-image}};
    
%placing ProdDesc first, such that ProdHeader and ProdTable can be placed relatively to it.
    \node[text width=80mm, minimum height=5mm, right= 2mm of imagebox.east] (ProdDesc){long\\description\\for\\emphasis\\of\\a\\real\\situation\\with\\lots\\of\\text};

    \node[text width=80mm, above= 2mm of ProdDesc.north] (ProdHeader){\huge{Header}};

    \node [below=2mm of ProdDesc.south](ProdTable){
    \begin{tblr}
    {width=80mm,colspec={*{3}{X}}}
    test & test & text \\
    test & test & test \\
    test & test & test \\
    \end{tblr}};

%making the fit boxes
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [inner ysep=0, minimum width=80mm,draw=blue, dashed, fit = (ProdHeader) (ProdDesc) (ProdTable)](CompBox) {};
    \node [inner ysep =2mm, minimum width= 130mm, draw, fit= (start) (imagebox) (CompBox)] (outerbox){};
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Is there an elegant way to group or make a bounding box around a collection of nodes for placement purposes? As this element is to be reused multiple times, I am reliant on relative positioning.

Comment: Do you really need Ti*k*Z? Do you only use it for alignment? Because I think you could also solve this with just one `tblr` environment.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I made my example simpler to keep clarity, but I use Tikz for some of the graphical elements of the actual setup, including; the outer box is a colored, filled path with a singular rounded corner; using the "current page" to place element outside margins, and so on. If there is a way to do this without Tikz, I wouldn't mind at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably position the nodes in a different order. I assume that the image should always be 25mm wide and thus, the left border of `(ProdDesc)` will always have the same distance from `(start)`.

Therefore, I would suggest that you first position `(ProdDesc)`, `(ProdHead)` and `(ProdTable)`, then `fit` `(CompBox)` and only then position `(imagebox)` relative to `(CompBox)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, backgrounds}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

%coordinate for use in fitting the outerbox correctly; box extended beyond page is intentional
\coordinate (start) at (current page.west);

%placing ProdDesc first, such that ProdHeader and ProdTable can be placed relatively to it.
\node[text width=80mm, minimum height=5mm, anchor=west] 
    (ProdDesc) at ([shift={(41.5mm,0)}]start)
    {long\\description\\for\\emphasis\\of\\a\\real\\situation\\with\\lots\\of\\text};

\node[text width=80mm, above=2mm of ProdDesc.north] 
    (ProdHeader) {\huge{Header}};

\node[below=2mm of ProdDesc.south] 
    (ProdTable) {
        \begin{tblr}
        {width=80mm,colspec={*{3}{X}}}
        test & test & text \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        \end{tblr}
    };
        
%making the fit boxes
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[inner ysep=0, minimum width=80mm, draw=blue, dashed, fit={(ProdHeader) (ProdDesc) (ProdTable)}] 
    (CompBox) {};
\end{scope}

%imagebox placement, works as intended
\node[draw, text width=25mm, minimum height=25mm, anchor=east, baseline=center] 
    (imagebox) at ([shift={(-2mm,0)}]CompBox.west) 
    {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, height=25mm, width=25mm, clip]{example-image}};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[inner ysep=2mm, minimum width=130mm, draw, fit={(start) (imagebox) (CompBox)}]    
    (outerbox) {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes you just stare at a problem so long, that you miss the obvious solution, and I definitely did this time. Thank you, that solves my problem completely.

Comment: @Fibecker You're welcome. I know this feeling ... =)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way without Tikz. Basic ideas:

- define macro `\intro`, which takes 4 parameters
- put a `\parbox` with the image, and another one for the texts

In the document you'll find 4 examples of using it:

1. with long description
2. with minimal description and without a table
3. with your tabular
4. with some `\tikz{}` as 4th parameter

Layout and positioning are determined by the lengths:

- `\hspace{12mm}`
- `\parbox{30mm}`...
- `\parbox{9cm}`...

And yes, there's no reason why you can't interchange the 3rd and 4th call, i.e. put the table before the description with this macro.

Recall, that you need to put a `%` as the very last thing per line to avoid trouble from spaces placed by typesetting.

Instead of using `\frame` you may prefer `\fbox` or `\framebox`.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\intro[4]{% image, header, decr, table
    \frame{% ~~~ put a frame on it ~~~~~~~~~~
        % ~~~ image ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \hspace{12mm}%  moving image to the right
        \parbox{30mm}{% will leave 5mm empty space to the right
            \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,%
                    height=25mm, width=25mm,clip]{#1}}%
        % ~~~ Text ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \parbox{9cm}{%  width of the text part
            \smallskip% some vertical space; or use \vspace{•}
            % ~~~ header {font localized} ~~~~~
            {\huge{#2}}%
            
            \smallskip%
            % ~~~ Description ~~~~~~~~~
            #3%
            \bigskip%
        
            % ~~~ Table or whatever ~~~~~~~~
            #4%     
            \smallskip}}}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

\begin{document}

 \intro{example-image}{This is the start}
                      {\lipsum[1]}{
                        \begin{tabular}{lll}
                             1 & abc & def\\
                             2 & ghi & jkl\\
                             \end{tabular}}

 \bigskip

 \intro{example-image}{Something else}{Very short description}{}

 \bigskip

 \intro{example-image}{Something else}{Somewhat short description}{
    \begin{tblr}
    {width=80mm,colspec={*{3}{X}}}
    test & test & text \\
    test & test & test \\
    test & test & test \\
    \end{tblr}
 }

 \bigskip

 \intro{example-image}{Something else}{Lazy description}{
    \tikz{
        \draw[red] (0,0) to[out=-10,in=140] (5,1);
    }
 }
 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I initially understood that the image had to be positioned absolutely on the page (relative to the `start` node), and not move when the content of the `CompBox` changes.

It seems that this is not the case. Anyway I post an answer to do so.

Since the size of the `CompBox` is not constant, the idea is to save it in a box

```tex
\newsavebox{\Prodbox}
\sbox{\Prodbox}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=80mm, minimum height=5mm] (ProdDesc){long\\description\\for\\emphasis\\of\\a\\real\\situation\\with\\lots\\of\\text};

    \node[text width=80mm, above= 2mm of ProdDesc.north] (ProdHeader){\huge{Header}};

    \node [below=2mm of ProdDesc.south](ProdTable){
      \begin{tblr}
        {width=80mm,colspec={*{3}{X}}}
        test & test & text \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
      \end{tblr}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

and recall it later in a node

```tex
\node[right=2mm of imagebox.east] (ProdBox)  {\usebox{\Prodbox}};
```

Note that there is no need that `\Prodbox` contains a `tikzpicture`. You can simply use a `minipage` instead.

Full code (with a larger `ProdTable` for the demonstration):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\Prodbox}
\sbox{\Prodbox}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=80mm, minimum height=5mm] (ProdDesc){long\\description\\for\\emphasis\\of\\a\\real\\situation\\with\\lots\\of\\text};

    \node[text width=80mm, above= 2mm of ProdDesc.north] (ProdHeader){\huge{Header}};

    \node [below=2mm of ProdDesc.south](ProdTable){
    \begin{tblr}
        {width=80mm,colspec={*{3}{X}}}
        test & test & text \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
        test & test & test \\
      \end{tblr}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]

  % coordinate for use in fitting the outerbox correctly; box extended beyond page is intentional
  \node [anchor=west] (start) at (current page.west){};

  % imagebox placement, works as intended
  \node[draw, text width=25mm, minimum height=25mm, anchor=west, baseline=center](imagebox) at ($(start)+(12mm,0)$) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=25mm, width=25mm,clip]{example-image}};

  % recall \Prodbox where you want
  \node[right=2mm of imagebox.east] (ProdBox)  {\usebox{\Prodbox}};

  % making the fit boxes
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node [inner ysep=0, minimum width=80mm,draw=blue, dashed, fit = (ProdBox)](CompBox) {};
    \node [inner ysep =2mm, minimum width= 130mm, draw, fit= (start) (imagebox) (CompBox)] (outerbox){};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image positioned absolutely]